# How do I modify this script to use different colors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page that has a 4x4 grid and two squares change color one white and the other black. I need to know how to ammend the script to make the color white appear before the black one.

Please could someone help me to solve this issue, the code is pasted below:

html:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"> </script> 
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="style1.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen> 
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="script1.js"> </SCRIPT> 
</head> 
<body>  
<div class="container">     
<div class="box spacing"></div>     
<div class="box spacing"></div>     
<div class="box spacing"></div>     
<div id="square1id" class="box"></div>      
<div class="box spacing"></div>     
<div class="box spacing"></div>     
<div id="square2id" class="box spacing"></div>     
<div class="box"></div>      
<div class="box spacing"></div>     
<div class="box spacing"></div>     
<div class="box spacing"></div>     
<div class="box"></div>      
<div class="box spacing"></div>     
<div class="box spacing"></div>     
<div class="box spacing"></div>     
<div class="box"></div> </div>  
</body> 
</html>
```

css:

```
body{
    background-color:#000000;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

h1{
  color:#ffffff;
  text-align:center;
}

.container{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:860px;
    margin-left:250px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.box{
    width:210px;
    height:120px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#4D4D4D;
    margin-bottom:3px;
}

.spacing{
    margin-right:3px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var colourinfo = {
    square1id: [
                '#FFE600'


                ],

    square2id: [
                '#008B45'


                ]

};

var count = 0;

var changecol = function(){
    $.each(colourinfo, function(tileid, colarray){
    $('#'+tileid).css('background-color', colarray[count%colarray.length]);
}); 
    count++;
    };
    setInterval(changecol, 1000);
    });
```

I would appreciate any help on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sets up an array where each element is an object giving the normal and highlight colour for each square. Called via setInterval() the changeColour() function changes the colour of the last square back to normal and the next square to highlight:

```
var colourInfo = [
    {id : "square1id",
      colourNormal : "#4D4D4D",
      colourHighlight : "#FFE600"},
     {id : "square2id",
      colourNormal : "#4D4D4D",
      colourHighlight : "#008B45"}
     // add your other squares' info here
    ];

var index = 0;
var changeColour = function(){
    $('#'+colourInfo[index]["id"]).css('background-color',
                    colourInfo[index]["colourNormal"]);
    if (++index >= colourInfo.length)
       index = 0;
    $('#'+colourInfo[index]["id"]).css('background-color',
                    colourInfo[index]["colourHighlight"]);
}

setInterval(changeColour,1000);
```

Note: the if statement in the middle of the changeColour() function just increments the index and keeps looping around and around the array in order. If you want the squares to change colour in random order you could replace the if statement with something like

`index = Math.floor(Math.random() * colourInfo.length);`

EDIT: I assumed above (due to David's use of setInterval()) that the idea was to keep changing the colours indefinitely. Now that I find the idea was to flash each square once I'd suggest the following (untested) change. (Yes, I know this is getting clunky, but I couldn't be bothered starting from scratch and I figure the point is to give David some ideas on how he *might* do it, not to do his work for him and present a beautifully unit-tested and documented masterpiece.)

```
var index = -1;
var changeColour = function(){
     if (index > -1) {
        $('#'+colourInfo[index]["id"]).css('background-color',
                     colourInfo[index]["colourNormal"]);
     }
     if (++index < colourInfo.length) {
        $('#'+colourInfo[index]["id"]).css('background-color',
                        colourInfo[index]["colourHighlight"]);
        setTimeout(changeColour,1000);
     }
}
setTimeout(changeColour,1000);
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help but this does not seem to work for me.

Comment: @David - sorry, there was a typo in my code (I'd done a funny copy-paste on two lines and ended up with `colourInfo[colourInfo[` instead of just `colourInfo[`. I think I've fixed it now. In any case here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kUaAW/ (note: I copied your HTML and CSS directly to jsfiddle without changing them, so I didn't bother to correct the ugly formatting that happened by default on paste, but the bit you care about is the JS...) - don't just copy this into your project though, read through it and be sure you understand it.

Comment: thank you so much your help is very much appreciated. If you could would you please be so kind to let me know if it is possible to stop the sequence once it has gone through. thanks

Comment: @David - see my updated but untested code above. If you're happy that this is close to what you need feel free to accept my answer.

Comment: @nnnnnn - excellent,I have tried jsfiddle.net/kUaAW solution & workout well for me. I'm also working on similar project but with 4 colors in sequence starting from the first. can you please advise on what are the changes required in script so as to sequence will starts with square1id and so on in cycle. At the moment its starting with square2id first and for the next cycle it starts from the 1st. I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @raul - taking the code I already posted (the first part of my answer), the simplest change to make it start with the first element is to change `var index = 0` to be `var index = -1`, then put in `if (index > -1)` before the first line of the `changeColor()` function. I.e., similar to the example at the end of my answer. It's a bit clunky, but again you're welcome to pretty it up.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the colors are set in colourInfo.  Try this:

```
  var colourinfo = {
        square1id: ['#FFFFFF'],

        square2id: ['#000000']

    };
```

Comment: Sorry I know where the colors are, I need to change the script to make the square1id appear before square2id. Thanks

Comment: Can't you just modify the HTML and swap the locations of the two divs?